# remove html before and after brackets

Tags: php, regex

I want to search twig file and remove paragraph tag before and after brackets.

Example :

```
<p>{% include 'footerEn.html' with vars %}</p>
```

to be :

```
{% include 'footer.html' with vars %}
```

and

```
<p>{# comment here....#}</p>
```

to be

```
{# comment here....#}
```

and

```
<p>{{....}}</p>
```

to be

```
{{....}}
```

Is it possible using Regex? I have tried some combinations but not working. This is all a single string. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: A regex should work fine, here is a simple one: `<p>(.*)<\/p>`

Comment: i tried above regex, but it did not work, please check below sample


<p>{# src....... #} {% set vars = {'ImagesPath': ImagesPath} %} {% include 'header.html' with vars %} Dear {{ body.firstName }} {{ body.lastName }}<br /><br /></p>
<p>Your text here.</p>
<p>Thank you for  this service....</p>
<p>{% include 'footer.html' with vars %}</p>


i want to remove  <p> before and after {%  %} or {# #} , and keep it in other places

Comment: If you want to introduce additional requirements or examples, please add them as an edit to your original question.

Comment: If you are printing the string than how about using str_replace(['<p>{', '}<p>'], '', $string)...

Comment: _I have tried some combinations but not working._ Please share what you have tried, as well as an explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex

```
/<p>({[%#{].*?[%#}]})<\/p>/
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/DvGNKp/1

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of capturing groups, an alternation and a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) `(?|` and match all 3 variations.

```
<p>(?|{#(.*?)#}|{%(.*?%)}|{{(.*?)}})</p>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T1vTf5/1)

In the replacement use the first capturing group `$1`